# Understanding this derivation of back propagation

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, neural-networks, numerical-calculus

I'm following along and trying to prove the 4 equations for back propagation in neural networks in [chapter 2 of this book](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap2.html):

Prove: \begin{eqnarray} 
  \delta^l = ((w^{l+1})^T \delta^{l+1}) \odot \sigma'(z^l) \nonumber\end{eqnarray}

However, I'm stuck on the very first step of this one, in which $\delta^l_j$ (error in activation of neuron $j$ in layer $l$) at a more advanced layer is related to the error in a previous layer:

\begin{eqnarray}
  \delta^l_j & = & \frac{\partial C}{\partial z^l_j} \tag{40}\\
  & = & \sum_k \frac{\partial C}{\partial z^{l+1}_k} \frac{\partial z^{l+1}_k}{\partial z^l_j} \tag{41}\\ 
  & = & \sum_k \frac{\partial z^{l+1}_k}{\partial z^l_j} \delta^{l+1}_k,
\tag{42}\end{eqnarray}

The chain rule is supposed to be at play here, and I certainly can see its form at work. However, the discrete nature of the problem has me a bit turned around. **Can someone simply explain the first step to me?**

As for the work I myself have done, it is relegated to a single self-contained layer, which is the first proof of the chapter. I was able to do it without reading ahead, which made me happy:

by definition, $C$ is a function of the activation $a^l_j = \sigma(z^l_j)$ where $z^l_j$ is the linear combination of weights and biases $z^l_j=\sum_k w^l_{jk}a^{l-1}_k + b_j$. So, by the chain rule, it's pretty trivial for me to say:

\begin{eqnarray}
  \delta^l_j & = & \frac{\partial C}{\partial z^l_j} \\
  & = & \frac{\partial C}{\partial a^l_j}\frac{\partial a^l_j}{\partial z^l_j}\\ 
  & = & \frac{\partial C}{\partial a^l_j}\sigma'(z^l_j)\end{eqnarray}

Your explanations, hints, pokes and prods are appreciated. This is not homework, so feel free to use as much or as little detail as you desire.

**Edit in response to comment:** @jeea, I've written $z^{l+1}_j = \sum_k w^{l+1}_{jk} \sigma(z^l_k)+ b^{l+1}_j$, which is the only way I can see to write one in terms of the previous. How this relates to the proof, I still cannot see.

Comment: I am not entirely sure but thinking of it as fullyconnected, then $z_j^{l}$ can be represented as comb of $z_k^{l+1}$ where $k$ runs through no. of neurons in $l+1$ layer. This follows from defn. of $z^{l+1}$ in terms of $z^{l}$. Then rest is direct app. of chain rule. Think of $z_j^{l}$  as variable $x$ and that it depends on $a, b$ which are $z$ of next layer. Then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial a}\cdot \frac{\partial a}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial b}\cdot\frac{\partial b}{\partial x}$ [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#General_rule)

Comment: First try writing $z^{l+1}_j$ that is $j$th neuron in terms of $z^{l}_k$ that is $k$th neuron of prev layer

Comment: @jeea Thanks, I'll give it a go!

Comment: @jeea I've followed your suggestion, and made an edit to the question showing that work. I still don't see how it relates. I can't see what you mean :/

Comment: I am saying that when you write the relations, you will realise that $z_k^{l}$ or some kth neuron in $l$th layer can be in turn written as a function of $z_j^{l+1}$ that is all neurons of next layer using that expression. For $z_k^{l}$ all $z_m^{l}$ where $m \neq k$ are necessarily constant. So first step ie eqn 41 is just that we are using $\sigma (z_k^{l}) = f(z_1^{l+1}, z_{2}^{l+1}...z_{n^{l+1}}^{l+1})$ and so we may apply/use chain rule